# Dont show values in dropdown initially

Tags: r, shiny

By default when user selects dropdown it shows all the values listed in `choices` argument. I want to show suggestions only when user starts typing on search box. I am using  `live-search = TRUE` for live suggestions as user enters in the search box.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

my_autocomplete_list <- c("ICICI Prudential aaaa","ICICI Prudential bbbb","ICICI Prudential ccccc", "Tata dddd","eeee")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "fundname",
        label = "Search Fund", 
        choices = my_autocomplete_list,
        options = list(title = "Search Fund",
                       `live-search` = TRUE)
      ),
      
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { }

# Run App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by some javascript:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

my_autocomplete_list <- c("ICICI Prudential aaaa","ICICI Prudential bbbb","ICICI Prudential ccccc", "Tata dddd","eeee")

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "fundname",
                label = "Search Fund", 
                choices = my_autocomplete_list,
                options = list(title = "Search Fund", showContent = FALSE,
                               `live-search` = TRUE)
            ),
            tags$script(HTML(
                "
                $('#fundname').on('show.bs.select', function(){
                    var input = $('.bootstrap-select:has(select[id=\"fundname\"]) .bs-searchbox > input');
                    var opts = $(this).parent().find('div[role=\"listbox\"] ul li');
                    opts.hide();
                    
                    input.on('input', function(e){
                        if ($(this).val() !== \"\") {opts.show();}
                        else {opts.hide();}
                    });
                });
                "
            )),
            actionButton("submit", "Submit")
        ),
        mainPanel(
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { }

# Run App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is what's happening: on dropdown open, hide all options. When users start to type, if the value is not empty, display the search results, otherwise keep options hidden.

Comment: Just a related question if you know any method - Is it possible to have this kind of functionality in SearchInput / TextInput? I mean I want live suggestions in search box. SearchInput seems right widget but does not allow live suggestions. The issue I have with PickerInput is user can't erase selected value by clicking on backspace (similar to search box functionality in any popular website)

Comment: Maybe use `selectizeInput`, this one allows you to use backspace, but then you need to figure out the code to hide options. It will not be the same as the js code here. They use a different js library. 
or you could use some live-search javascript libraries. Google, [lunr](https://lunrjs.com/), google search API, [algolia search](https://www.algolia.com/).